# jQuery - Easy slider plugin images "truncated"

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I implemented and slightly modified the [easy slider](http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider) jQuery plugin.

The problem is that ***sometimes*** the images dong get fully loaded.

Here is an image:

[image]

Here is how it should be:
[image]

It seems to be quite random, but whenever I do a hard refresh, (cmd+shift+r or ctrl+f5) it works everytime.

I´m not quite sure where the problem might be.

I give you a [live example](http://chaletpuntadeleste.com/), hoping it helps, I would give you the code I used (but most you can see in the example) and I would know what to show you.

I hope I´m not being to vague, please ask if you need any clarification.

Thanks in advance!

Trufa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/window.onload) instead of [`document.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) here (the main difference being that images are loaded when `onload` fires), like this:

```
$(window).load(function(){  
  $("#slider").easySlider({
    auto: false, 
    continuous: true
  });
});
```

When Easy slider is calculating heights and such, your images need to be loaded, running the plugin at the appropriate time should resolve that...since it won't run *until* they're loaded and have the right dimensions.

Comment: Worked like a charm, and thanks a lot for the extra explanation, very helpful!!